# multiply columns based on values in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes. My goal is to create a new column with the product of the multiplication from
the column "number" and the column "multiplier" based on the name column.

First DataFrame:

```
id  name    number
1   aa      3
2   aa      6       
3   bb      2   
4   bb      8
5   cc      3
```

Second Data Frame:

```
id  name    multiplier
20  aa      2
21  bb      4
23  cc      6
```

Result:

```
id  name    number  product
1   aa      3       6
2   aa      6       12  
3   bb      2       8
4   bb      8       32
5   cc      3       18
```

Comment: why haven't you created any code yet? You should have the dataframes defined for us etc..  at the very least.

Comment: @MikeQ With `pandas.read_clipboard()`, there is really no more need for "defining the dataframes."

Comment: @DYZ interesting, though I think the poster should be obligated to show something they had tried to do etc..

Comment: @MikeQ I do not disagree with the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2[['name', 'multiplier']], on='name')
df3['product'] = df3['number'] * df3['multiplier']
print(df3)

## -- End pasted text --
   id name  number  multiplier  product
0   1   aa       3           2        6
1   2   aa       6           2       12
2   3   bb       2           4        8
3   4   bb       8           4       32
4   5   cc       3           6       18
```

Comment: Same as my answer :)

Comment: @NYCCoder Close. In your case, the id column will be copied over from both left and right sides. Other than that, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily set the index of each dataframe to "name" and simply do the multiplication. Then reset the index.

```
first['product'] = (first.set_index('name')['number'] * \
                    second.set_index('name')['multiplier'])\
                   .reset_index()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `merge`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['name'])
df['product'] = df['number'] * df['multiplier']
print(df[['name', 'number', 'product']])

  name  number  product
0   aa       3        6
1   aa       6       12
2   bb       2        8
3   bb       8       32
4   cc       3       18
```

Comment: I thought there is a nicer approach, but I'll take it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use you can use `df.multiply()` after setting the index. Once multiply is done reset the index.

```
df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df1['product'] = df1['number'].multiply(df2['multiplier'])
df1
```

---

```
    id  number  product
name            
aa  1   3   6
aa  2   6   12
bb  3   2   8
bb  4   8   32
cc  5   3   18
```

---

```
df1.reset_index()
```

---

```
    name    id  number  product
0   aa      1   3       6
1   aa      2   6       12
2   bb      3   2       8
3   bb      4   8       32
4   cc      5   3       18
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach. This one sets the index of `df2` to the `'name'` column and then indexes into it with the `'name'` column of `df1` to obtain the factors.

```
>>> factors = df2.set_index('name').loc[df1['name'], 'multiplier'].values
>>> df1['number'] *= factors
>>> df1
   id name  number
0   1   aa       6
1   2   aa      12
2   3   bb       8
3   4   bb      32
4   5   cc      18
```